# A product of intervals where the indexing set is all bounded sequences; Generalizing the limit of a sequence so that it is always defined.

Tags: general-topology, product-space

This problem seems very hard to me, and any hints will be greatly appreciated.

**Here is the question:**

Let S be the space of bounded real sequences; for each $a\in S$ let $M_a$ be its least upper bound; let $X=\prod\limits_{a\in S}[-M_a,M_a]$; let $\alpha\colon\mathbb N\rightarrow X$ be the map defined by $(\alpha(n))_a=a(n)$; let $\beta\mathbb N$ be the closure of $\alpha(\mathbb N)$ in X.

(a) Prove that $\beta\mathbb N$ is compact and that $\alpha(\mathbb N)$ is a dense homeomorphic copy of $\mathbb N$ inside of $\beta\mathbb N$. Conclude that $\beta\mathbb N\neq \alpha(\mathbb N).$

(b) Prove for each $a\in S$ there exists a unique continuous function $\overline{a}\colon\beta\mathbb N\rightarrow [-M_a,M_a]$ such that $a=\overline{a}\circ\alpha$.

(c) Let $\mu\in\beta\mathbb N\smallsetminus\alpha(\mathbb N)$. Define $\lim_\mu(a)=\overline{a}(\mu)$. Prove that $\lim_\mu$ is always defined, if $a_k\rightarrow l$ then $\lim_\mu(a)=l$, and that $\lim_\mu$ is multiplicative and linear.

(d) Show that if $a,b\in S$ such that $b$ is obtained from $a$ by $b_k=a_{k+1}$, then it's not necessarily the case that $\lim_\mu(a)=\lim_\mu(b)$.

(e) Let $b=(0,1,0,1,\ldots)$, what can you say about $\lim_\mu(b)$?

**Here is what I have done so far**

(a) $\beta\mathbb N$ is a closed subspace of a compact space so it is compact. By definition $\alpha(\mathbb N)$ is dense in $\beta\mathbb N$. I have managed to prove that $\mathbb N\cong\alpha(\mathbb N)$ in the discrete topology. $\alpha$ is the homoemorphism, and $\alpha(\mathbb N)$ is not compact since $\mathbb N$ is not compact.

(b) I have managed to prove this part without too much difficulty. I took $\overline{a}$ to be the restriction of the projection map onto the $a'th$ component.

(c) I have managed to prove that $\lim_\mu$ agrees with the limits of convergent sequences. I'm not sure how to show that it is linear and multiplicative. If the sequences $a$ and $b$ are convergent then it just follows from the regular limit laws, but I don't know how to treat the case when $a$ or $b$ is not convergent.

(d) and (e) I think that these parts are related. I think that $\lim_\mu(b)$ can either be $0$ or $1$ depending on which $\mu$ we pick, and that the shifted sequence will have the other limit. I'm not sure if I'm thinking about this correctly though.

Comment: for (c) note that if $a$ and $b$ are bounded sequences, so is $a+b$ defined as $(a+b)(n)  = a(n) + b(n)$. Clearly $\alpha(a+b) = \alpha(a) + \alpha(b)$ holds on $\mathbb{N}$. So it also holds on its closure $\beta(N)$ (if two continuous functions agree on a dense set, they agree everywhere, for Hausdorff codomain).

Comment: I think you're right that the shifted sequence of $b$ has another limit. As $\alpha(b) = \{0,1\}$, we have $\lim_\mu(b) \in \{0,1\}$ as the image space is compact, so the closure stays inside it.

Comment: Okay I think I can prove (c) now. We have $\overline{a+b}(\alpha(n))=(a+b)(n)=a(n)+b(n)=\overline{a}(\alpha(n))+\overline{b}(\alpha(n))$, so $\overline{a+b}=\overline{a}+\overline{b}$ everywhere on the dense set $\alpha(\mathbb N)$, so this should imply they are also equal on the closure, which would give $\lim_\mu(a+b)=\lim_\mu(a)+\lim_\mu(b)$. And it would be similar for multiplication. I will think more about (d). Thanks for the help!